# How can you find which .NET project reference is transitively loading another assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I've got a project that I'm trying to deploy to another PC, but the installation fails because it requires an assembly to have been installed in the GAC. But that assembly (System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting 4.0.0.0) has no relevance to my project so I'm trying to remove both it and the direct reference that loads it.

My project *--directly depends on-->*  **Unknown reference**  *--indirectly depends on-->*  System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting 4.0.0.0

How can I find out which of the direct references in my project is indirectly loading this useless DomainServices assembly? I can't see a way to do it using reflection...

(This is a general question, but if it helps I'm using C# on .NET 4.0, Visual Studio 2010, and ClickOnce to deploy the project.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try turning on [Fusion Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309346%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), this will enable you to view all of the assembly load failures.

[Back to Basics: Using Fusion Log Viewer to Debug Obscure Loader Errors](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)

Comment: This is a good solution and has helped me out, thanks. However, it seems you need Visual Studio installed to run Fusion Logging? Is it possible to install it by itself if we have this issue on a PC with no VS?

Comment: This is awesome. Ive never heard of Fusion til this post. My problem was that i had a test proj that compiled fine but I couldn't step into it with the debugger when it ran because the directly ref'd assembly's were being wiped from bin at compile. I couldn't work it out until i looked at the compile output window which basically said system.web was referencing the wrong .Net version i.e. client profile. This was easy enough to fix but then I found myself wondering, "this is a winforms.app, whats reffing system.web?" It looked like id have manually search for the ref till this post. v cool thx

Answer (score 0):

Try to find it with Reflector. Also note that the Assembly class has a GetReferencedAssemblies method, so you should be able to find it with reflection, too.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies() but that will only tell me the **directly** referenced assemblies from my project, which is something that I already know (and which you can also find out using VS Debug, procexp, etc...). I'm looking for the **indirect/transitive** references.

Reflector is handy if I go through each of the direct references one-by-one and examine it. Is there a faster way of doing this? This must be a common use case.